# Combining ne(0), Lookup & Backfill over a Subset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which I need to calculate the first nonzero occurrence of a particular field, identify the corresponding value in another field, then backfill a new field with that value.

Easier with an example.  I **HAVE** the first three columns, I need to get the "Reported Column" as the first date in which the "loss" column is non-zero (will always be gt zero).

```
Claim   |   Loss    |   Date       |  Reported
-------------------------------------------
 A      |    0      |  2019-01-01  | 2019-03-01
 A      |    0      |  2019-02-01  | 2019-03-01
 A      |    500    |  2019-03-01  | 2019-03-01
 A      |    500    |  2019-04-01  | 2019-03-01
 -----------------------------------------------
 B      |    0      |  2019-01-01  | 2019-04-01
 B      |    0      |  2019-02-01  | 2019-04-01
 B      |    0      |  2019-03-01  | 2019-04-01
 B      |    500    |  2019-04-01  | 2019-04-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way,

```
df = df.sort_values(['Claim', 'Date'])
df['Reported'] = df.assign(Reported=df['Date'].mask(df['Loss'] == 0)).groupby('Claim')['Reported'].transform('first')
df
```

Output:

```
  Claim   Loss         Date     Reported
1     A    0.0   2019-01-01   2019-03-01
2     A    0.0   2019-02-01   2019-03-01
3     A  500.0   2019-03-01   2019-03-01
4     A  500.0   2019-04-01   2019-03-01
6     B    0.0   2019-01-01   2019-04-01
7     B    0.0   2019-02-01   2019-04-01
8     B    0.0   2019-03-01   2019-04-01
9     B  500.0   2019-04-01   2019-04-01
```